# XPath: what's the different between "begin with one slash" and "begin with 2 slashes"?

Tags: select, xpath, slash

I read some Xpath code, some begin with "/xxxx", some begin with "//xxxx". What're their differences? Do they have different behavior just in "Select" or different also in other behaviors?

I didn't find corresponding explanations on this site, any hints?

Thanks.

Comment: You might find [the tag wiki for xpath](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xpath/info) useful. To see a tag's wiki, click the tag itself then click learn more

Comment: A decent tutorial on XPath 1.0 is at http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html. Any tutorial should cover `/` and `//`.

Comment: If the first place you are looking for answers to questions is "this site", then your strategy for learning the language is seriously flawed. Get yourself a good XPath reference book, and read it.

Comment: Some people aren't trying to "learn the language" but rather just need to get some obscure feature working so they can get back to their real jobs.  If people shouldn't ask questions here when the answer is already in a book somewhere, there would be very few questions asked.

Answer (score 4):

Beginning an XPath with one slash will retrieve the root of the document, so that `/xxxx` will match only the `<xxxx>` element that is the root of the XML.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xxxx> <!-- this one will match -->
  <level>
   <xxxx /> <!-- this one won't -->
  </level>
</xxxx>
```

Whereas `//xxxx` will match all `<xxxx>` elements **anywhere** in the document.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xxxx> <!-- this one will match -->
  <level>
   <xxxx /> <!-- this one will match as well -->
   <sublevel>
     <xxxx /> <!-- and also this one -->
    </sublevel>
  </level>
</xxxx>
```